# Adding post commits to Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post-commit, campfire

I am using the following gem in my rails application:

```
http://github.com/fnando/post_commit
```

I am trying to learn how to send data to service providers such as Campfire on creation of a record in my application.

Using Campfire as a test I have the following in my kase.rb model:

```
# Campfire
post_commit :campfire do
authorize :subdomain => "XXXXXXXXXX", :token => "XXXXXXXXXXXX", :room => 'XXXXXXX'
post "New Record", :type => :text
end
```

the following in my kases_controller.rb:

```
  # POST /kases
  # POST /kases.xml
  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:kase][:company_id])
    @kase = @company.kases.create!(params[:kase])

    respond_to do |format|
        @kase.sendtocampfire if params[:send_to_campfire]

        #flash[:notice] = 'Record was successfully created.'
        flash[:notice] = fading_flash_message("Record was successfully created.", 5)

        format.html { redirect_to(@kase) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @kase, :status => :created, :location => @kase }
    end
  end
```

and the following in my view:

```
    <%= check_box_tag :send_to_campfire, 1, true %> Send Case to Campfire?
```

When using the code above, I get an error of:

```
NoMethodError in KasesController#create

undefined method `post_commit' for #<Class:0x10528e3e8>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to explicitly `require` the `post_commit` before use or, better still, make sure you have the following in `environment.rb` in your `Rails::Initializer.run` block

```
config.gem 'post_commit'
```

Comment: Hi, if I add config.gem 'post_commit' the error changes to: NoMethodError in KasesController#create

undefined method `sendtocampfire' for #<Kase:0x105177dd8>

Comment: @dannymcc So do you have a method called `sendtocampfire` in your `Kase` model? Is that what wraps the `post_commit` call?

Comment: Hi, The following is in my Kase model:   # Campfire
    post_commit :campfire do
        authorize :subdomain => "dannyweb", :token => "820d410dc1850659cfa2bb440efa3ae1b106786d", :room => 'McClelland & Co'
        post "New Case created in Survey Manager", :type => :text
    end -- I don't know if that's correct or not? Thanks, Danny

Comment: Just realised I was missing def sendtocampfire from the kase.rb. Sadly though, after that I don't get any errors but the message isn't sent to Campfire - could be an issue with the room name though...